# Can I get the JavaScript to execute in an SVG image that is appended to the DOM with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg, innerhtml, inline-svg

I would like to append an SVG image to my HTML and have the JavaScript in the SVG execute.

Let's say I'd like to fetch [this image](https://cdn.rawgit.com/jormaturkenburg/42bf377e390839b6fd75745403fface7/raw/2de81dff93fbb214216ac9f332dfebecad864da1/circle.svg) and drop it into my HTML with something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test SVG</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var listener = function(response) {
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = this.responseText;
        };
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.addEventListener('load', listener);
        request.open('GET', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/jormaturkenburg/42bf377e390839b6fd75745403fface7/raw/4c851457ae03f0b416d122b7538bc6d9dc794954/circle.svg');
        request.send();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Hello world!</div>
    <div id="output">
        Inner HTML
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkvmwj7L/)

The SVG image has a console.log() and an alert() in its script tag. These execute just fine when viewing the image but not when appending the image to the HTML by JavaScript. Is there a way to do this and get the JavaScript to execute?

I know they'll execute if I were to embed the image but I need to inline it with JavaScript.

Comment: @RobertLongson, the JavaScript is in a script tag inside the SVG image. How do I get to it? If you look at the source of [this image](https://rawgit.com/jormaturkenburg/42bf377e390839b6fd75745403fface7/raw/4272d10bd974f646e2400d4c7e5d31ab7b6ded5a/circle.svg). There's a function test. Calling test() in the page after loading the SVG gives me an error. Is there another way to get to that function?

Comment: That's my question. How do I get to it? I tried calling test() in the global scope but that doesn't work. I can get to the SVG object after it's set as innerHTML to the #output div but then what?

Comment: As per the duplicate I linked this question to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>    
<object id="svgholder" data="some.svg" type="image/svg+xml""></object>
</body>


var svgholder = $('body').find("object#svgholder");

svgholder.load("image/svg+xml", function() {
    alert("some svg loaded");
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!